# Compare two CSV files using Java with the condition to ignore a particular column in both

Tags: java, csv

I need to to compare two CSV files using Java.

I have two CSV files (containing, for example, 10 columns). Among 10, one of the columns contains a Date-Time value. The files are generated at a different time, hence these values will never match. I have to compare these two files ignoring the Date-Time column.

Any help over this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of the columns that will contain the date time value ahead of time, simply check the index of columns before you compare them to make sure they are not the date time columns.

Otherwise, check the first value of the column, and if it is a date time value, then do not proceed.